# How to find correlated values in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Say you have a table such as:

```
id   foreign_key  status
------------------------
1    1            new
2    1            incative
3    1            approved
4    2            new
5    2            new
6    2            approved
7    3            new
8    3            approved
9    4            approved
```

How to find records where the for a given foreign_key there is only one record in status new and the other are approved, like in case of foreign_key 3?

Comment: if any of the answered DID answer your question, please mark it as an answer so that it help others to know that this question had been answered..thnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select foreign_key from table
group by foreign_key
having 
   abs(1 - count(case status when 'new' then 1 end)) + 
   abs(count(1) - 1 - count(case status when 'approved' then 1 end)) = 0
```

Comment: nice but it's finding cases when one record is incactive. I need only exactly one is new and all others are approved.

Comment: @Thomas - [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/14971).  Thanks to Ramblin' Man for this demo code.

Comment: Sorry Egor, it works. I must have made a mistake yesterday. Can you explain the code to me a little bit, it's so slick, I'd love to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
Select *
from 
(
   Select foreign_key
     from table
    where status = 'new'
    group by foreign_key
    having count(1) = 1
) new_st
inner join
(
   Select foreign_key
     from table
    where status = 'approved'
    group by foreign_key
    having count(1) = (select count(1)-1 from table t1 where t1.foreign_key =foreign_key)
) app_st
on new_st.foreign_key = app_st.foreign_key
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT id, foreign_key, status,
               COUNT (DECODE (status, 'new', 1))
                  OVER (PARTITION BY foreign_key)
                  new_count,
               COUNT (DECODE (status, 'approved', 1))
                  OVER (PARTITION BY foreign_key)
                  approved_count,
               COUNT (status) OVER (PARTITION BY foreign_key) total_count
          FROM mytable)
 WHERE new_count = 1 AND new_count + approved_count = total_count;
```

I have used 3 different counts. One to count new, one to count approved and one to count all status. Finally select only those records where new_count = 1 and new_count + approved_count is equal to total_count.

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/14970).

*EDIT:* Can add `approved_count > 0` condition to make sure that there is atleast one approved status.